# Is there anyway to take a string input in zoo::rollmean() in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, input, shiny, zoo

I'm creating a Shiny App for the first time and am running into an issue with inputs and outputs with reactiv.

I am taking input from a user for a state, type of data, and rolling average to create a plot for Coronavirus data.

For zoo::rollmean() to work, I need to have a straight column object name, such as rollmean(deaths, k=3, fill=NA).

How do I take a string input and put it into the rollmean() function? I've searched for an answer for a while and wasn't able to find anything. Thanks!

**This code will not work:**

ui:

```
selectInput(inputId = "data_point", 
  selected = "deaths", 
  label = "Type of Data,
  choices = c("Deaths" = "deaths",
              "Tests" = "people_tested",
              "Confirmed Cases" = "confirmed",
              "Recovered" = "recovered"))
```

server:

```
  output$covid_plot <- renderPlot({
    statedata %>%
      arrange(desc(state)) %>% 
      group_by(state) %>% 
      mutate(three_day = rollmean(input$data_point, k = 3, fill = NA),
             five_day = rollmean(input$data_point, k = 5, fill = NA),
             seven_day = rollmean(input$data_point, k = 7, fill = NA),
             fifteen_day = rollmean(input$data_point, k = 15, fill = NA))
```

**This code will:**

ui:

```
selectInput(inputId = "data_point", 
  selected = "deaths", 
  label = "Type of Data,
  choices = c("Deaths" = "deaths",
              "Tests" = "people_tested",
              "Confirmed Cases" = "confirmed",
              "Recovered" = "recovered"))
```

server:

```
output$covid_plot <- renderPlot({
 statedata %>%
 arrange(desc(state)) %>% 
 group_by(state) %>% 
 mutate(three_day = rollmean(deaths, k = 3, fill = NA),
      five_day = rollmean(deaths, k = 5, fill = NA),
      seven_day = rollmean(deaths, k = 7, fill = NA),
      fifteen_day = rollmean(deaths, k = 15, fill = NA))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faking the `shiny`-like environment:

```r
input <- list(var = "disp")
```

### Base R

```r
head(mtcars) %>%
  mutate(z = zoo::rollmean(get(input$var), k = 3, fill = NA))
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb        z
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       NA
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 142.6667
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 175.3333
# 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 242.0000
# 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 281.0000
# 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1       NA
```

### `tidyeval`

```r
inp <- sym(input$var)
head(mtcars) %>%
  mutate(z = zoo::rollmean(!!inp, k = 3, fill = NA))
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb        z
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       NA
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 142.6667
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 175.3333
# 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 242.0000
# 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 281.0000
# 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1       NA
```

or just

```r
head(mtcars) %>%
  mutate(z = zoo::rollmean(!!sym(input$var), k = 3, fill = NA))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly. I tried !!input$var before but couldn't get it to work, good to know I was missing the sym(). Thanks again.